# What is the difference/relationship between drools pipeline and drools server

Tags: drools

when I come to find a service which can expose web service API to execute the drools rules remotely.

I firstly find the drools-camel-server, while sometimes I see there is module called drools-server, in order to find relationship between drools-camel-server and drools-server, I google a lot. but I find another module called drools-pipeline http://kijanowski.eu/index.php?site=articles&article=drools_pipeline&lang=en

after reading, I find the concept is sth similar to drools-camel-server, I read the drools-camel-server here http://www.packtpub.com/article/drools-integration-modules-spring-framework-apache-camel

I can distinguish drools-server and drools-camel-server, drools-server should be able to provide the remote execution function already, but camel added the enterprise integration pattern, so now we mostly use the drools-camel-server.

but what about drools-pipeline? is it the rudiment of drools-server? but I see the pipeline concept should be the camel's.

Anyone can explain them a little would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

drools-pipeline is deprecated, pre drools-camel work.

For drools 6, drools-camel has been improved a lot IIRC.

Comment: But why I can see there is updated version of drools-pipeline?
http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.drools/drools-pipeline/
from 5.2.0 to 5.5.0, on some website, I even see 6.0